# Tensorflow gradient returns none

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient

I am trying to calculate the gradient of the option price y respect to the input spot price. Here is my code. Now it seems like gradient is not none, but it returns tensor error, which I think I did it correctly.

```
def vanilla_price(X):
moneyness_inverse = X.iloc[:, 0]
sig = X.iloc[:, 1]
r = X.iloc[:, 2]
T = X.iloc[:, 3]
d1 = (np.log(moneyness_inverse) + (r + 0.5 * sig ** 2) * T) / (sig* 
np.sqrt(T))
d2 = (np.log(moneyness_inverse) + (r - 0.5 * sig ** 2)* T) / (sig * np.sqrt(T))

    
result = ((moneyness_inverse) * ss.norm.cdf(d1, 0.0, 1.0) -  np.exp(-r * T) * ss.norm.cdf(d2, 0.0, 1.0))

return result

spot = 100.001
spot = 100.001
weight = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(np.array(X), dtype 
='float32')

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
   g.watch(weight)
   y = vanilla_price(weight)
    

jacob_actual = g.gradient(y, weight)[:, 0]
print(jacob_actual)
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-231-c20368558cc7> in <module>
  3 
  4 with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
  ----> 5     g.watch(weight)
  6     y = vanilla_price(weight)
  7 

  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\backprop.py in 
  watch(self, tensor)
  848               pywrap_tensorflow.IsVariable(t)):
  849         raise ValueError("Passed in object of type {}, not 
  tf.Tensor".format(
  --> 850             type(t)))
   851       if not t.dtype.is_floating:
   852         logging.log_first_n(

   ValueError: Passed in object of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, not 
   tf.Tensor
```

Can anyone give me a hint or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you expect there would be any gradient between those tensors? Each of them is an independent variable. Gradients can only be computed for a tensor with respect to another tensor which took part in its computation. E.g. if you had `y_tf_tensor = 3 * X_tf_tensor` then you would be able to compute the gradient (which would be `3` for all values of `X_tf_tensor`).

Comment: well from my understanding, y depends on spot price, using black scholes formula. y was computed using bs formula with inputs(one of them is spot).

Comment: None of that computation seems to be present in your code, TensorFlow cannot guess such things, as the above comment says, you are presenting this data as two independent variables to TensorFlow. Mathematically there is no gradient to be computed, so None is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have edited so that it does not return none can you take a look at it?